# Bootstrap stacking inputs on div resize

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I would like to know how to use Bootstrap responsive columns when resizing a containing div, and not just the viewport size.

I would like the inputs inside the form to stack side by side as I make the modal wider.

Html :

```
<button>open
</button>
<div class="modal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="pesquisa_modal" style="pointer-events: none">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header bg-primary text-white" id="header" style="cursor: move">
            Modal
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-auto">
                <label for="Form1">Form1</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Form1">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-auto">
                <label for="Form2">Form2</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Form2" >
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-auto">
                <label for="Form3">Form3</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Form3">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-auto">
                <label for="Form4">Form4</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Form4">
              </div>
            </div>
         </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/p204kwjz/6/

Can I make the inputs continue to stack horizontally as I enlarge the containing div? 
The problem is that that the inputs are not "fluid" when I enlarge the div wide enough to fit them all in a row. Also, when the containing div is too small they overflow the div horizontally.

The context here is that the forms will be created dynamically, so I need some kind of smart layouting.

Comment: You've tagged this as twitter-bootstrap(bootstrap 2/3) and bootstrap 4, is there one you prefer?

Comment: @JonathanChaplin I'm using 4, just thought the other was any version

Comment: The reason your resizable isn't working is because you're missing the jquery ui css add this link to your project: https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

Comment: @JonathanChaplin Thanks, updated the question and the fiddle

Comment: It's not clear from your question, do  you want forms to stack horizontally or vertically

Comment: @JonathanChaplin I want them to stack smartly, because in my context they are created dinamycally

Comment: I'm a little confused about the term "stack smartly", but I'll take a guess. If you're in phone portrait orientation stack forms vertically, and as the screen gets wider stack forms next to each other (horizontally, 2x2 grid).

Comment: @JonathanChaplin Yes, but keep stacking the more I enlarge the modal, if you check the fiddle it already works like that, but once its too large there is a gap because the inputs are not evenly distributed or flowing the full row size

Comment: Got it. My answer below.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your columns to take up the full width (stack horizontally) in bootstrap use `col-md-12` on your form and wrap it in a div with class `form-row`. Basically bootstrap assumes each row is composed of 12 columns.

```
<div class="modal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="pesquisa_modal" style="pointer-events: none">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header bg-primary text-white" id="header" style="cursor: move">
            Modal
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label for="Form1">Form1</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Form1">
              </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">              
              <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label for="Form2">Form2</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Form2" >
              </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">              
              <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label for="Form3">Form3</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Form3">
              </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">              
              <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label for="Form4">Form4</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Form4">
              </div>
            </div>
         </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/p204kwjz/7/)

Answer (score 0):

The form-group and the col-auto classes aren't playing nicely.  You can achieve fluid inputs by nesting col-auto inside form-group

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5pqz8849/)

```
<button>open
</button>
<div class="modal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="pesquisa_modal" style="pointer-events: none">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header bg-primary text-white" id="header" style="cursor: move">
    Modal
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-auto">
            <label for="Form1">Form1</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Form1">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-auto">
            <label for="Form2">Form2</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Form2">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-auto">
            <label for="Form3">Form3</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Form3">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-auto">
            <label for="Form4">Form4</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Form4">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but I didn't see the difference from my fiddle in practical terms, it seems to behave the same?

Comment: It's because you need a column class that spans all 12 columns like col-md-12

Answer (score 0):

You are using bootstrap 4.
In bootstrap 4, if you code for medium, say 2 divs of col-md-6 and use in smaller screen, div takes the full width and stacking happens, ie: both the divs are one above the other.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0px;
  padding 0px;
}

.col-md-6 {
  /* Assuming that col-md-6 width is 1000px */
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:red;">
    Sri harsha
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:blue;">
    Achyuthuni
  </div>
</div>
```

That is because, unlike Bootstrap 3, Bootstrap 4 is made using flex boxes.
To see how flex works, look into this [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

See how aspects of the Bootstrap grid system work across multiple devices with a handy [table](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/).